# UIActivityIndicatorView stops spinning

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am experiencing that when I add a `UIActivityIndicatorView` as a subview of one of my `UITableViewCell`s then it only spins for a short while and then it stops. Does anyone maybe know why?

This is in principle what I am doing in my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) cell.accessoryView = spinner;

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    label.text = @"Some text";

    return cell;
}
```

where `spinner` is an `IBOutlet`:

```
IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
```

Comment: when do you want spin the activity indicator? whether loading data in tableview or before load the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inserting this inside the function.

```
[spinner startAnimating];
```

If you want it to stop, call the stopAnimating method.

Comment: I thought checking the animation checkbox for the spinner in my story board corresponded to `[spinner startAnimating]` - also because it was actually spinning in the beginning! Well, inserting a `[spinner startAnimating]`  directly in my code actually made it spin forever! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually start and stop the animation of the UIActivityIndicatroView.
Example for your code

Add this where you want to start the animation:

```
[spinner startAnimating];
```

Add this where you want to stop the animation:

```
[spinner stopAnimating];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I thought checking the animation checkbox for the spinner in my story board corresponded to `[spinner startAnimating]` - also because it was actually spinning in the beginning! Well, inserting a `[spinner startAnimating]`  directly in my code actually made it spin forever! Thanks! :) As T Chad answered first I had to accept his answer though.